# Sum of three square is a square and sum of their product taken two at a time is also a square

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory

Let  $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = X^2$  and

$$(ab)^2 + (ac)^2 + (bc)^2 = Y^2$$
Such that $a,b,c,x,y$ are all non zero Integers.

How to find All solutions ?

Is there any parametrization which gives Infinitely many solutions ?

What is the smallest solution for above equation ?

Comment: $a=b=y=0$, $c=\pm x$.

Comment: There are two solutions $(a, b, c)$ such that $1  \le a, b, c \le 200$ and $\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$: $(96, 72, 35)$, $(144, 57, 44)$.

Comment: For above equations If abc is non zero then i call it as a nontrivial solution.

Comment: Shall we assume that lowercase x equals uppercase X and likewise for y and Y ?

Comment: @Daniel Asimov, Yes.

Comment: @Guruprasad. FYI, I have added another method of solution today to my existing answer.

Answer (score 13):

According to Tito Piezas's website [$9. (x^2+y^2+z^2, x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2)$](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326022229/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/007),

one of the solutions is
$(x,y,z) = (p^2+q^2-r^2,  2pr,  2qr)$ where $(p,q,r) = (8n(n^2-1),  n^4-10n^2+5,  n(n^2+1)(n^2-3)).$

Answer (score 2):

$a^2+b^2+c^2=(X)^2$  ------------ (1)

$(ab)^2 + (ac)^2 + (bc)^2 = Y^2$ ----- (2)

The solution given by Euler gives a smallest numerical value for 'Y' in the six digits.

We take:

$(a,b,c)=[(8uv),(6uv),(5u^2-5v^2)]$

& we get:

$x=(5u^2+5v^2)$

Substituting above in:

$y^2=a^2(b^2+c^2)+b^2c^2$,

we get:

$Y^2=(2uv)^2[625(u^2-v^2)^2+(24uv)^2]$ ----(3)

Above is a square at (u,v)=(4,3)

And we have:

$(a,b,c)=(96,72,35)$  &

$(X,Y)=(125,8088)$

Addendum (1):

There are more numerical solutions for equations (1) & (2) & using equation (3) above as shown by Seiji Tomita via Email & is given below:

Case (A),

$(u,v)= [25, 7]$,

$(a,b,c)=[1400, 1050, 2880]$

Case (B),

$(u,v)=[8088, 4375]$,

$(a,b,c)=[283080000, 212310000, 231375595]$

Case (C),

$(u,v)=[9559, 4841]$,

$(a,b,c)=[370200952, 277650714, 339696000]$

Addendum (2):

The parametric solution given by Euler has a factor,$(n^2+1)$, which after being removed gives us a smaller numerical solution namely:

$(a,b,c)=(76,192,513)$

The revised Identity of his, reads as follows:

$a=16n^2(n^2-1)(n^2-3)$

$b=2n(n^2-3)(n^4-10n^2+5)$

$c=(n^2+5)(n^2-1)(n^4-10n^2+5)$

And we get:

$x=(n^8-4n^6+46n^4-52n^2+25)$

$y=2n(n^2-3)(n^2-10)(n^4-10n^2+5)(n^6+27n^4-13n^2+25)$

For $n=2$, we have:

$(a,b,c,x)=(76,192,513,553)$  &

$y=(106932)$

---

Addendum (3):

Consider:

$p^2+q^2+r^2=X^2$   And

$q^2(p^2+r^2)+(pr)^2=Y^2$

We have the well known Identity:

$(2ab-2cd)^2+(2ac+2bd)^2+(a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$

Above is numbered as equation (1):

In order to reduce the number of variables in Identity (1) we take, (2a=5b) & $c=2d$ & we get:

$p=4(5b^2-4d^2)$,$q=48bd$,$r=3(7b^2-4d^2)$

And we get:

$X=(29b^2+20d^2)$

We substitute above in:

$q^2(p^2+r^2)+(pr)^2=Y^2$

we get:

$Y=4w$,   where:

$(4w)^2$ is equal to:

$(11025m^4+90864m^3n-133920m^2n^2+43776mn^3+2304n^4)$

Above is numbered as equation (2),

where, $(m,n)=(b^2,d^2)$

We note that equation (2) is a square at:

$(m,n)=(16,9)$ & we get, $Y=10668$

Also, $(m,n)=(16,9)$ is one of the numerical solutions to equation (2).

Hence we get: $(b,d)=(4,3)$

Since,  $2a=5b$ & $c=2d$  we get:

$(a,b,c,d)=(10,4,6,3)$

Therefore:

$(p,q,r,X,Y)=(44,144,57,161,10668)$